# how to set html class or id dynamically using angular

Tags: html, angular

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="container__usernamesContainer">
            <a class="container__usernamesContainer--text" *ngFor="let user of getUsers()">
                Username: {{ user.getUsername() }}
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="container__statusesContainer">
            <span class="container__statusesContainer--text" *ngFor="let status of getUsers()">
                <span [ngClass]="'{{ user.getUsername() }}'">
                    Status: {{ status.getStatusLabel() }}
                </span>
            </span>   
        </div>
    </div>
```

i am trying to set `[ngClass]="'{{ user.getUsername() }}'"` dynamically, and i do not get the value. how can i achive that?

Comment: Try `[ngClass]="{{ user.getUsername }}"` without the single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things going on here. You have two different *ngFor loops both iterating over the array returned by getUsers(). One you do let users of getUser(), and the other you do let status of getUsers(). But you then try to uncalled user instead of status in the second loop. Below is what your code should be.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container__usernamesContainer">
        <a class="container__usernamesContainer--text" *ngFor="let user of getUsers()">
            Username: {{ user.getUsername() }}
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="container__statusesContainer">
        <span class="container__statusesContainer--text" *ngFor="let status of getUsers()">
            <span [ngClass]="status.getUsername()">
                Status: {{ status.getStatusLabel() }}
            </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using property binding you don't need to use interpolation:

```
[ngClass]="user.getUsername"
```

You just need to bind the property that you want to use